# Sharekit Action Sheet showing more than 3 buttons?

Tags: ios, ipad, sharekit

Does anyone have any idea how I can have the Sharekit actions sheet showing more than 3 buttons?

I have made a couple of changes to Sharekit, (got rid of the 'more button' and specified 5 favourite sharers), however whenever the action sheet pops up after tapping the share button only 3 of the 5 I have specified show?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by setting up the favorites array (terminating with a nil) like this:

```
[SHK setFavorites:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKMail",@"SHKTextMessage",@"SHKTwitter",@"SHKFacebook",nil] forType:SHKShareTypeURL];
```

In this case the action sheet will show 4 services plus the MORE button for a total of 5 buttons.  Be sure the share type is matching what you're looking to setup.

I didn't need to do this but note in the SHKConfig.h file there is an entry for max faves:

```
#define SHK_MAX_FAV_COUNT           3
```

I didn't need to modify this to get to 5 buttons on the action sheet.